# How to deal with string primites in angularjs and $http?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

An ASP.NET Web Api function returns a simple string in JSON.

When I call this function from angularjs, I get a quoted string, not a simple string:

```
return $http.post('/api/orders', data).then(function (results) {
        return result.data;
```

result.data is `"my string"`, with quotes. It is due because the returned message is a string primitive, not a object. How is the appropriate way to deal with it? Removing quotes using a js function? Forcing to server to return a object instead of primitive? some special configuration? ...?

UPDATE:

The server uses a Web Api controller that returns a string:

```
 public IHttpActionResult SaveOrder() {return Ok("this is a test");}
```

it has the same result that:

```
 public string  SaveOrder() {return "this is a test";}
```

The problem is that the returned JSON value is not an object, it is directly the string primitive.

Comment: did you configured your `asp.net web api` to return `json`? it will help if you include your server side logic

Comment: We've actually seen this on the server-side many times and had to adjust for the removal of strings ...

Comment: In my opinion it will be better to return object (at least I was not able to configure server a year ago. I spent about 20 min for it and decided to use objects). So it's interesting question for me too ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. It happens because you are returning `string` from your controller, I assume it looks something like this:

```
public string ControllerMethod(..) {...}
```

You should be returning `HttpResponseMessage` instead of `string`, and the object will be like this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage ControllerMethod() 
{
    var myString = "my string";
    return new HttpResponseMessage()
    {
        Content = new StringContent(myString, Encoding.UTF8, "text/html")
    };
}
```

Comment: To avoid creating a response message you could simply return an `IHttpActionResult` and then just do: `return Ok("my string");`. This will do the content negotiation for you.

Comment: `retun Ok("my string")` has the same problem that I exposed. Precisely Omri uses HttpResponseMessage to avoid this problem.

Comment: @DabielKabuto Are you still having issues ?

Comment: No, your response worked fine. I was intrigued to know if there was a more general way to do it (like some configuration, etc.).
Thank you,