# POST parameter to web api being set as null

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, ngresource

I'm trying to use `ng-resource` to POST a value to my web-api and get the value back in javascript.

While the request seems to go through alright, the parameter being passed to my function `public string AddOrder([FromBody]string order)` seems to be set as `null`.

orderController.js

```
var result = $scope.store.sendOrder("hello");
```

store.js

```
function store($resource) {

    var Resource = $resource('/api/products/');
    this.products = Resource.query();

    this.sendOrder = function (order) {

        var sendOrder = $resource('/api/products');

        var result = sendOrder.save("Helloa"); <---

        return result;
    }
}
```

ProductController.cs

```
[Route("api/products")]
[HttpPost]
public string AddOrder([FromBody]string order)
{
    return order; //When I put a breakpoint here and check the value of order, it is null.
}
```

raw request

```
POST http://localhost:12345/api/products HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:12345
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 6
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost:12345
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost:12345/Home/Cart
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6,en-US;q=0.4
Cookie: ai_user=fc592beca77b4a5e8c4a95db221a574a|2014-12-04T18:36:22.7128874+00:00

hello
```

raw reply

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcbXJ5YW4uQVNBVklFXERvY3VtZW50c1xleHByZXNzb1xFeHByZXNzb1x3ZWJzaXRlc1xjb25zdW1lclxhcGlccHJvZHVjdHM=?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 12 Jan 2015 10:45:03 GMT
Content-Length: 4

null
```

Anybody have any ideas?

**Edit**

The quickest / easiest solution to this was to wrap the string in an object as follows:

Order.cs

```
public class Order
{
    public string order { get; set; }
}
```

ProductController.cs

```
[Route("api/products")]
[HttpPost]
public Order AddOrder([FromBody]Order order)
{
    return order;
}
```

Comment: Though a little different in symptoms, the problem might be that you are returning `string` from your controller instead of `HttpResponseMessage`. Look at my answer here, hope it helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27580145/how-to-deal-with-string-primites-in-angularjs-and-http/27580296#27580296

Comment: When I put a breakpoint at `return order;` and check the value of `[FromBody]string order`, it is null. So it seems that value being passed into `AddOrder` is null

Comment: Yeah I had issues with that too at the time. I gave up and passed an object wrapping the string instead.

Comment: Looks like that is exactly what I'm going to do, post that as an answer sure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I'm not sure what causes the string to be null in the controller, instead of posting a string to the Web API controller you could send an object wrapping up the string instead and that would be accepted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

To post to a string to the web api it needs to be preceded by `=`.Also there is no `Content-Type` set on the request.

```
  var sendOrder = $resource('/api/products',{}, { query: {method:'POST', headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

  var result = sendOrder.save("=" + "Helloa");
```

The above should work

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint in the controller and seeing the value there.

Comment: Yeah, it appears to be passed to function as null. I think that [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21035849/asp-net-web-api-post-parameter-is-null?rq=1) question is related

Comment: I have adjusted my answer give that a go

Comment: No luck with that either